# What are the benefits of running multiple Spark tasks in the same JVM?

Tags: java, scala, performance, apache-spark, jvm

Different sources (e.g. [1](https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html) and  [2](https://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/top-5-mistakes-to-avoid-when-writing-apache-spark-applications)) claim that *Spark can benefit from running multiple tasks in the same JVM*. But they don't explain why.

What are these benefits?

Answer (score 6):

As it was already said broadcast variables is one thing.

Another are problems with concurrency. Take a look at this of code:

```
var counter = 0
var rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

rdd.foreach(x => counter += x)

println(counter)
```

The result may be different depending, whether executed locally or on a Spark deployed on clusters (with different JVM). In the latter case the `parallelize` method splits the computation between the executors. The closure (environment needed for every node to do its task) is computed, which means, that every executor receives a copy of `counter`. Each executor sees its own copy of the variable, thus the result of the calculation is 0, as none of the executor referenced the right object. Within one JVM on the other hand `counter` is visible to every worker.

Of course there is a way to avoid that - using `Acumulator`s ([see here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators)).

Last but not least when persisting `RDD`s in memory (default `cache` method storage level is `MEMORY_ONLY`), it will be visible within single JVM. This can also be overcome by using `OFF_HEAP` (this is experimental in 2.4.0). More [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence).

Answer (score 5):

The biggest possible advantage is shared memory, in particular handling broadcasted objects. Because these objects are considered read-only there can be shared between multiple threads.

In scenario when you use a single task / executor you need a copy for each JVM so with N tasks there is N copies. With large objects this can be a serious overhead.

Same logic can be applied to other shared objects.

Comment: I saw broadcast variables mentioned in this context [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/). However, I find it hard to believe that it's only about broadcast variables.

Comment: Can the threads running in the same JVM share cached data (partitions)? This could allow to optimize shuffling, because partitions processed by a single executor could be shuffled in memory, without writing them to disk. But this is only a speculation on my side, I don't know if this is possible.